# Overriding the thumbnail of a single file using WinAPI

Tags: windows, shell, winapi, thumbnails, shell-extensions

I'm making my own thumbnail manager because I needed some obscure features.
I implemented `IThumbnailProvider`, and it mostly works, but now I'm trying to make some basic UI.

One of the things I got stuck on is the equivalent of a feature of "Media Preview":
In the "Testing and Cache" tab you can drag-n-drop files to check and regenerate their thumbnails.
Somehow, "Media Preview" immediately updates the thumbnails of those files in explorer, but I only managed to read an existing thumbnail for a file.

---

I'm pretty sure it's not about something like permissions.
VisualStudio is running as admin (only while I'm trying to get anything working ofc).
UAC is dead, and so are Windows Defender and Firewall.
And in the script registering the `IThumbnailProvider` implementation, I added `DisableProcessIsolation=1` so it can report every problem to me.

---

`SHChangeNotify` is not it. It notifies the system to check, but there needs to be an actual change (in the registry or file itself) for `IThumbnailProvider` to be called.
For instance, if I change the last write time of the file before calling `SHChangeNotify` - it works. But, needless to say, that's not a solution.

---

My latest try is based on Phind's suggestion on how to read thumbnails (when I asked how to override them). Nevertheless, I checked the interfaces and found `ISharedBitmap::InitializeBitmap`. At least I can't find any other use for it. I mean, [from msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/thumbcache/nn-thumbcache-isharedbitmap#remarks) - `ISharedBitmap` is only returned from 2 methods of `IThumbnailCache`, so surely it would have something to do with my case...

Anyway, here is what I've done in my dummy "Test" project:

```
    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("091162a4-bc96-411f-aae8-c5122cd03363")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ISharedBitmap
    {

        uint GetSharedBitmap(
            [Out] out IntPtr phbm
        );

        uint GetSize(
            [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] out SIZE pSize
        );

        uint GetFormat(
            [Out] out WTS_ALPHATYPE pat
        );

        uint InitializeBitmap(
            [In] IntPtr hbm,
            [In] WTS_ALPHATYPE wtsAT
        );

        uint Detach(
            [Out] out IntPtr phbm
        );

    }
```

This is the only part of the definitions I'm still anxious about. At first, the order of methods was the same as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/thumbcache/nn-thumbcache-isharedbitmap#methods), as it was on [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/ISharedBitmap.html), but `GetFormat` was returning the bitmap size, etc., so I reordered them as [here](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/Shell/trait.ISharedBitmap_Impl.html).

Then, in the method using them:

```
    public static void ReplaceThumbnail(string filePath, string newThumbnailPath)
    {
        var newThumbnail = new Bitmap(newThumbnailPath);

        SHCreateItemFromParsingName(filePath, IntPtr.Zero, typeof(IShellItem).GUID, out var item);

        var CLSID_LocalThumbnailCache = new Guid("50EF4544-AC9F-4A8E-B21B-8A26180DB13F");
        var thumbnailCache = (IThumbnailCache)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_LocalThumbnailCache, true)!)!;

        thumbnailCache.GetThumbnail(item, int.MaxValue, WTS_FLAGS.WTS_INCACHEONLY, out var sharedBitmap, out var cacheFlags, out _);

        var res1 = sharedBitmap.GetFormat(out var format);

        var res2 = sharedBitmap.GetSize(out var size);

        var res3 = sharedBitmap.GetSharedBitmap(out var hbmp);

        Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hbmp).Save(@"G:\0Prog\Thumbnailer\Test\1.bmp");

        //var bd = newThumbnail.LockBits(new Rectangle(default, newThumbnail.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        //sharedBitmap.InitializeBitmap(bd.Scan0, WTS_ALPHATYPE.WTSAT_RGB);
        var res4 = sharedBitmap.InitializeBitmap(newThumbnail.GetHbitmap(), WTS_ALPHATYPE.WTSAT_ARGB);

        var res5 = sharedBitmap.GetSharedBitmap(out var hbmp2);

        Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hbmp2).Save(@"G:\0Prog\Thumbnailer\Test\2.bmp");

        thumbnailCache.GetThumbnail(item, int.MaxValue, WTS_FLAGS.WTS_INCACHEONLY, out var sharedBitmap2, out var cacheFlags2, out _);

        var res6 = sharedBitmap2.GetSharedBitmap(out var hbmp3);

        Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hbmp3).Save(@"G:\0Prog\Thumbnailer\Test\3.bmp");

        //SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_ALLEVENTS, HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATHW, filePath, IntPtr.Zero);

    }

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    static extern void SHChangeNotify(
        HChangeNotifyEventID wEventId,
        HChangeNotifyFlags uFlags,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string dwItem1,
        IntPtr dwItem2
    );
```

Looking in debug:

- Every `resN` (error code) is 0.
- `hbmp2` is the exact same handle as passed to `.InitializeBitmap`
- `bd.Scan0` is accepted by `.InitializeBitmap`, unlike any random handle value, but then I can't `Bitmap.FromHbitmap` it after I get it back.
- format is `WTSAT_RGB`, size is `1280 x 720`, all as expected.
- `1.bmp` is the thumbnail I see in Explorer, the same as what my implementation of `IThumbnailProvider` generated, tho a bit downscaled. `3.bmp` is its exact copy, so only the local instance of `ISharedBitmap` was changed by `.InitializeBitmap`.
- My implementation of `IThumbnailProvider` is not overriding the thumbnail right after. I log it when it is called. And, well, it isn't.

Also, as a side note, if `.InitializeBitmap` is in fact the intended mechanism for overriding thumbnails - it is a very bad interface. Because `.GetThumbnail` refuses to give any kind of `ISharedBitmap` if the implementation of `IThumbnailProvider` has failed (or returned an empty result).
While for the purposes of just overriding the thumbnail - the success of `IThumbnailProvider` should not matter.

---

So, what am I doing wrong here? Is there any other WinAPI to set the thumbnail of a specific file?

Comment: ISharedBitmap has nothing to do with replacing thumbnails. Thumbnail system use a thumbnail cache id provided by the system https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-thumbnailcacheid. This id is either computed by the system (using a combo of dates, size, etc.) or given by a Shell Namespace Exension (irrelevant here). Calling SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, etc.) should work, *provided something has really changed in date or size* or anything the system uses to determine the file has changed and the thumbnail should be recomputed.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I already figured I could update the last write time to make the system recompute the thumbnail. But that's a very ugly solution when what I want is to take a single picture file and replace the thumbnail of a specified file with it. And it's ok if later the system recomputes the thumbnail and replaces it back to what it was.

Comment: If nothing changes, there's no reason for the thumbnail to change, unless you're the one who computes the thumbnail id (and you're not). Have you tried SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM)? using SHCNE_ALLEVENTS is wrong. Otherwise you can try this  https://gist.github.com/smourier/50673230c3756d5ee5f95f0080ee8f3c

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks, this is already better than touching the file in question. And yes, after deleting the thumbnail I now need to either call `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM)` or press F5 in Explorer.
Can you please also describe where you found `IThumbnailCachePrivate`? My first thought was digging through sources, but then I would expect scrappers like MagnumDB to also know about this interface. And they don't.

Comment: P.S. Skipped over this, but to answer you - yes, I tried `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM)` and on its own still doesn't do anything. So `IThumbnailCachePrivate` is in fact needed.

Comment: MagnumDb (which I wrote) is not a scrapper, it's more a parser of official SDK headers. It doesn't know because it's undocumented (although it does know about some undocumented GUIDs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254512/discussion-between-sun-serega-and-simon-mourier).